# Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jersey, openshift

I am trying to deploy my Jersey project from eclipse on openshift and I am getting this error in the tail files `Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host`

before when I had like this:

```
String host = "jdbc:mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/bustrackerserver"
```

I got this error:

> 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: “OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT”'

- I have pinged this ip address `127.10.230.440` and I am getting response
- I checked whether some of the port 8080, 3306 are being used from my local mashine but they are just being used  from eclipse.

Apple class.

```
package org.busTracker.serverSide;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * Root resource (exposed at "myresource" path)
 */
@Path("myresource")
public class Apple {

    //String host = " jdbc:mysql://${env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/serv‌​erside";
    //String host = "jdbc:mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/bustrackerserver";
    String host = "jdbc:mysql://127.10.230.440:3306/bustrackerserver";
    String user = "adminNMccsBr";
    String password = "K3SV5rbxh8qP";


    /**
     * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
     * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
     *
     * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {

        Connection conn = null;  
        try {    
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");    
          System.out.println("Connecting to database…");    
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host,user,password);    

          Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
          for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
              System.out.format("%s=%s%n",
                                envName,
                                env.get(envName));
          }



        } catch (Exception e) {    
          e.printStackTrace();    
        } finally {    
          if (conn != null) {    
            try {    
              conn.close();    
            } catch (SQLException e) {    
              // ignore    
            }    
          }    
        }   

        return "Hello, from apple class  14.05.15 13:30!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that `127.x.x.x` addresses are loopback addresses?  They don't go off the local machine / virtual machine.

Comment: @StephenC: hm I dont realy know what does that mean but i have tried it with the envirment variable and I got this error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: “OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT` what else do I have to replace it with?

Comment: I just want to deploy my Jersey  project (Tomcat 7, phpmyadmin, mysql 5.5) in servlet container. Does that to manage with openshift?

Comment: This link explains what a loopback address is: http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPReservedPrivateandLoopbackAddresses.htm.  Given that you don't recognize the term, I suspect that this is the root cause of your problem.

Comment: The problem was I had to use `System.getenv().get()` to set the host string `  String host = "jdbc:mysql://"
    + System.getenv().get("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST") + ":"
    + System.getenv().get("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT")
    + "/serverSide";`

Answer (score 2):

Your MySQL is *not* listening on TCP/IP and hence your attempt to connect is failing.  You sort of answered your question when you said:

> I checked whether some of the port 8080, 3306 are being used from my local mashine but they are just being used from eclipse.

In other words, MySQL is *not* listening on localhost.  To confirm this another way, try connecting to MySQL from the command prompt:

```
mysql -u adminNMccsBr -h 127.10.230.440 -p YOUR_DB_NAME
```

I expect this to fail.  The solution to your problem is to configure MySQL to listen on localhost.  In the `/etc/my.cnf` config file, under the [mysqld] line, add the following:

```
bind-address = 127.10.230.440
```

This is not a Java problem, it's a MySQL problem.

Comment: I tried to execute your command from the prompt comands but I am getting somthing like `The command mysql can not be regognized`.  In my.ini file I had `#bind-address="127.0.0.1"` I changed it to  `bind-address="127.10.230.440"` but nothing changed. But what I noticed too I tried to access `phpmyadmin` from XAMPP and I can not do it any more. I think it was the case when I installed openshift plugin in eclipse  and not because this line was changed `bind-address="127.10.230.440"` since I set this line to the old status but I am still not able to access my phpmyadmin.

Comment: Is that a problem because XAMMP is listing to port 3306 too? I saw it now on the GUI of XAMMP . I am using widnows 8.

Comment: Try killing XAMMP and see what happens.  You should really try connecting to MySQL from the command line, because you want to rule out any potential problems coming from the Java layer.  If you can't connect from the command line, then the problem still lies with MySQL.