# How can I connect to mariadb using java?

Tags: java, mariadb

I've used:

```
Connection  connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "username", "password"
);
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE a (id int not null primary key, value varchar(20))");
stmt.close();
connection.close();
```

but it gives an error "No route to host"

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30238472/2873538)?

Comment: yes,i also use class.forName(org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver)

Comment: Are the ports 8080 and 3306 free as discussed in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30238472/2873538) post?

Comment: Port 3306 is used to connect with mariadb as mysql.jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test

Comment: try to connect to `mysql` from command prompt: `mysql -u username -h localhost -P 3306 -p your_db_name`

Comment: This i tried already the i got the prompt as ,Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 35
Server version: 5.5.49-MariaDB-1ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE DATABASE db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> use db;
Database changed

Comment: Don't you have to open the connection first?

Comment: how can we open the connection

Comment: yes,i connected it using mysql -u username -h localhost -P 3306 -p your_db_name.But cant access through java program

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Java MariaDB example:

```
//STEP 1. Import required packages
package mariadb;

import java.sql.*;

public class Mariadb {
    // JDBC driver name and database URL

    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mariadb://192.168.100.174/db";

    //  Database credentials
    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "root";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");

            //STEP 3: Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mariadb://192.168.100.174/db", "root", "root");
            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

            //STEP 4: Execute a query
            System.out.println("Creating table in given database...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "CREATE TABLE REGISTRATION "
                    + "(id INTEGER not NULL, "
                    + " first VARCHAR(255), "
                    + " last VARCHAR(255), "
                    + " age INTEGER, "
                    + " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))";

            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Created table in given database...");
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            //Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //finally block used to close resources
            try {
                if (stmt != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException se) {
            }// do nothing
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }//end finally try
        }//end try
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }//end main
}//end JDBCExample
```

I use this example.I change the bind address to 127.10.230.440. and i restart the server   sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start .

List item

Answer (score 3):

```
public class ConnectionDemo {
    String userName,password,url,driver;
    Connection con;
    Statement st;

    public ConnectionDemo() {
        userName="root";
        password="root";
        url="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/stud";
        driver="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        st=con.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Connection is successful");
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with TCP/IP port . Mariadb is not listening to the local host.
You should try : Configure mariadb to listen on localhost. 
In the `/etc/my.cnf` config file, under the [mysqld] line, add the following:

`bind-address = 127.10.230.440`

Or try to disconnect the MYSQL database first.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the reason have been that I had the wrong driver. You need a mariadb-java-client-XXX.jar (NO Source version!) and add it to the classpath. With that it was work fine, I hope that I was able to help a bit.